# truncating long author lists in citation call-outs to "firstauthor et al"

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{johd}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{johd}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

An entry in my bib.bib file reads:

```
@book{khandker2009handbook,
  title={Handbook on impact evaluation: quantitative methods and practices},
  author={Khandker, Shahidur R and Koolwal, Gayatri B and Samad, Hussain A},
  year={2009},
  publisher={World Bank Publications}
}
```

The first time I do `\cite{khandker2009handbook}` I get `Khandker, Koolwal, & Samad (2009)`. Second time onwards, I get `Khandker et al. (2009)`.

Any idea how to make it appear as `Khandker et al. (2009)` from the first time?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a copy of the bibliography style file `johd.bst` -- I guess "johd" is an abbreviation of "Journal of Open Humanities Data" -- and the LaTeX package file `johd.sty` at [this location](https://www.overleaf.com/project/62584e91e382ea7a945e05d1).

The first line of the bst file says:

> %% With the exception of the format.doi function, johd.bst is identical to apacite (metadata from apacite.bst are kept intact).

And line 14 of `johd.sty` says:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

At this point, it seems like a rather promising idea to consult the user guide of the `apacite` package, doesn't it? (By the way, the `apacite` package implements the formatting guidelines of the 6th edition of the APA manual. The 6th edition is no longer the most recent one.) Typing `texdoc apacite` at a command prompt opens the package's user guide file in a pdf browser. On page 15 of the user guide, under the sectioning header "Using natbib for citiations", one finds this passage:

> With the `natbibapa` option, `apacite` loads `natbib` with the options `longnamesfirst` and `sort`. The former [option tells BibTeX to] insert the full author lists in the first citation and the short author lists in subsequent citations, ...

The behavior you've "discovered" thus definitely occurs by design. If you've been told (say, by a journal's submission guidelines) to use the `johd` package and associated bib style, I would therefore *not* change any settings and just learn to live with the resulting look of the citation call-outs.

If, on the other hand, you are using the `johd` package out of your own free will, I suppose there's nothing to stop you from opening the file `johd.sty` in a text editor and deleting the `natbibapa` option, is there? Do be aware though that by eliminating the `natbibapa` option, you'll also lose all other benefits afforded by that option, such as being able to run `\citet` and `\citep` to create text-style and parenthetic-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!